# Get Parameter passed to the action in a CodeIgniter Hook

Tags: codeigniter, hook, acl

I' m trying to create a ACL for CodeIgniter and got stuck at one point.

I cannot figure out how to get the parameter passed to method.
For example the url looks like this:
`http://ci.dev/controller/action/31`

I managed to get the controller and method/action like this:

```
$class = $CI->router->fetch_class();
$method = $CI->router->fetch_method();
```

However I cannot figure out how to get the parameter (in this example 31).
This is kinda essential for me, since I want to control whether a user is allowed to edit items which belong to another user.

I do not want to use any kind of URI-fetching, just because the route might look different sometimes, e.g.:`http://ci.dev/controller/31/action`

Just as a little extra information, I' m with the `post_controller_constructor` hook.

I want to be prepared for this.

Any help is very appreciated.
Thanks in advanced.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The [URI Library](http://ellislab.com/codeigniter/user-guide/libraries/uri.html) has methods specifically for retrieving the post-routed details. These methods usually have `r` somewhere in it, like `rsegment()` for example.

`$CI->uri->rsegment_array()` would probably be sufficient. There's nothing specifically for parameters, but you can knock off the first two array items and the rest will be your parameters.